# How to match the key word using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a keyword, for example, "SOS fire". I want to find it in the list based on using Regex. When I define directly, it can be working well, but seem it's not passed the reference for the `keyword`.

```cs
//2023 - 07 - 07 14:30:27,266 | datatemp 1 | datatemp x | SOS fire //match
//2023 - 07 - 07 14:30:27,266 | datatemp 2 | datatemp y | Data SOS beach //not match
//2023 - 07 - 07 14:30:27,266 | datatemp 3 | datatemp z | SOS fire homes //match
var str = "2023-07-07 14:30:27,266|datatemp 1|datatemp x |SOS fire \r\n2023-07-07 14:30:27,266|datatemp 2|datatemp y |Data SOS beach \r\n2023-07-07 14:30:27,266|datatemp 3|datatemp z |SOS fire homes ";
var list = str.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
var keyword = "SOS fire";
var count = 0;
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(item.TrimStart().TrimEnd(), @"\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|\b("" + keyword + "")\b"))
    {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

So, any idea for this case, give me some advice. I have tried this option, it can be found:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to print out the string literal, you will see the result:

> |(.+?)|(.+?)|\b(" + keyword + ")\b

There is not proper way to assign the value with string literal. Instead, you should use `String.Format()`.

```cs
String.Format(@"\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|\b({0})\b", keyword)
```

And declare the compiled regex instead of creating uncompiled regex for each time in the loop to improve the performance. Reference: [The Regular Expressions Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/compilation-and-reuse-in-regular-expressions#the-regular-expressions-cache)

```cs
Regex regex = new Regex(String.Format(@"\|(.+?)\|(.+?)\|\b({0})\b", keyword));
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (regex.IsMatch(item.TrimStart().TrimEnd()))
    {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ETdMzd)

Comment: This could be improved by passing the keyword through [Regex.Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape) so any characters with special meaning within a Regex (e.g. ?) are properly escaped.

Comment: @KlausGütter, when using Regex.Escape, we need define start character and end character if have. Finally, it looks like ```string.contains```  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0